# Subject-complement agreement - a member of a committee vs members of a committee

Tags: grammar, meaning

I wonder if there is any difference between the following two sentences?

1. They are a member of a committee.
2. They are members of a committee.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, it is the [singular use of they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they), whereas the second example, it is a plural usage. Singular they is often used to be gender-neutral, instead of using he or she.

If you were referring to a single person, then the first form would be correct. However, if you were referring to more than one person, the second form would be correct.

Comment: are they both correct?